# Решить систему уравнений sympy

Tags: python, математика, sympy

Нужно найти кривую пересечения двух цилиндров, расположенных под 90° вдоль оси Z друг к другу.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy.vector import *

M = Matrix([[1,0,0], #Матрица координат для первого цилиндра
            [0,1,0],
            [0,0,1]])

N = Matrix([[0,0,1], #Матрица координат для второго цилиндра
            [1,0,0],
            [0,1,0]])

HC = Matrix([R*cos(alpha),R*sin(alpha),z]) # сам цилиндр

FC1 = M*HC #поворот первого цилиндра(по факту - на 0°)
FC2 = N*HC #Поворот второго цилиндра(на 90°)
FC3 = FC1-FC2 # Нужно решить уравнение FC3==0 - это и будет искомая кривая(FC3 - это векторная функция).
```

Помогите решить посредством sympy.

Answer (score 1):

В общем идея в том чтобы избавиться от alpha

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy.vector import *
M = Matrix([[1,0,0], #Матрица координат для первого цилиндра
            [0,1,0],
            [0,0,1]])

N = Matrix([[0,0,1], #Матрица координат для второго цилиндра
            [1,0,0],
            [0,1,0]])

hx=R*cos(alpha)
hy=R*sin(alpha)

alpha=[solve([hx-x,hy-y])[0][alpha],solve([hx-x,hy-y])[1][alpha]] # два решения


HC1 = Matrix([R*cos(alpha[0])-x,R*sin(alpha[0])-y,z]) # от первой и второй альфы
HC2 = Matrix([R*cos(alpha[1])-x,R*sin(alpha[1])-y,z])

# проверяем

FC1 = solve(M*HC1-N*HC1,x,minimal=True) # вернет два решения
print FC1

FC2 = solve(M*HC2-N*HC1,x,minimal=True) # вернет два решения
print FC2

FC3 = solve(M*HC1-N*HC2,x,minimal=True) # вернет два решения
print FC3

FC4 = solve(M*HC2-N*HC2,x,minimal=True) # вернет два решения
print FC4
```

Единственное почему-то FC(1-4) одинаковы, может просто два решения должно получиться а не восемь